# How Can I Access My Desktop's File System Over 3G?

Tags: cyanogenmod, files, remote-access

I'm looking for a good solution to be able to browse my home computer and download files remotely. I've tried Gmote, and it works pretty well, but for some reason the desktop client seems to randomly shut down and I'm unable to access it until I go home and restart the client. I'd rather have a way to connect just by my IP address (I'm aware that my IP can change; I can always set up a dyndns account) and a port number, with a username and password.

I'm on a Motorola Droid running CyanogenMod 6.1 (Froyo).

EDIT: My desktop is running Windows 7 64-bit.

Any suggestions on ways to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could setup a FTP server on your computer and use [AndFTP](http://www.appbrain.com/app/andftp/lysesoft.andftp) to connect to it.

Comment: An FTP server could work, I'll look into AndFTP when I get home. I tried SwiFTP before, and I never could get it connected.

Comment: It might be an idea to setup a VPN on your local machine so it is more secure.

Answer (score 1):

Comment:

You probably were unable to get it to work because you may not have had the ftp server set up first. You will need to set up an ftp server on your machine and open the appropriate ports for it to function correctly. Are you running windows, linux or mac?

Comment: I did try setting up an FTP server first; I think FileZilla and SmartFTP were the two I tried. Preferably I'd rather not have a client running if possible, but it may be the easier option. I added the desktop details, it's running Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Google 'set up ftp server windows 7' and stuff like that, you will come by some great tutorials on how to set up a ftp server on your machine. If you run into snags go by the server exchange and see if they can help you any. I am sure they will be a great help!

Comment: Thanks to both of you! I'll be sure to give these a try later.

Answer (score 1):

You could sign up for DropBox and install their Android app.

http://www.dropbox.com/android

Comment: Thanks, I've got Dropbox actually, but I don't upload everything there. Basically, I had an annoyance yesterday trying to get a file printed, my flash drive just stopped working completely, I didn't have it in Dropbox. I had to drive home, burn it to a CD and come back. I just realized it'd be much easier if I could just access my documents from my phone and email it wherever I needed.